# Swapping currency when swapping languages

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, multi-site

Folks:

I have a multilingual and multicurrency site. All works fine when switching currencies or languages independent of one another. But is there a way to have the currency switch when the language is switched? For example, if the user selects German, the currency is switched to Euros.

To complicate matters, I am using GeoMate to detect the IP and redirect to the appropriate language. Can I switch to the correct currency when they are automatically redirected to their language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch currencies in the following ways:

https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/payment-currencies.html#switching-currencies

It looks like GeoMate would need to add support to switch the currency for you using one of the above methods.